# Windows service not processing requests

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, pubnub

We have a windows service which has been installed in multiple client machine and working  perfectly fine from past few years.

But from few days we have observed that the service is not processing any pubnub requests we also have heartbeat check which happens for every 1 minute which is working fine in few machines but requests are not being processing. where as in few machines even the heartbeat check is also not happening.

Restarting the service s fixing the issue but it is again occuring after few days and we have observed this issue only in few clients.

Comment: Do you see anything show up in the client logs? https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/c-sharp/troubleshooting

Comment: Code would be helpful as well as environment details like OS/version, and such. And you could send details (and logs as Darryn recommended) to support@pubnub.com.

Comment: Salandri Shruti - just curious if you ever contacted our support team and if the issue was ever resolved.